# Precisely visualize sets

Tags: data-visualization

I have three sets and I know their size and their intersection size, say :

```
  A size = 1000
  A intersect B size = 200
  B size = 3000
  B intersect C = 120
  C size = 5000
  A intersect C = 0
```

Is that possible to visualize these sets with an Excel bubble chart precisely?
Is there any free tool for **windows** to visualize these sets

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: In general there are many possibilities consistent with these data, depending on the size of $A\cap B\cap C$. However, the limited data you provide determine a *unique* such (Venn) diagram because the set sizes and their intersection sizes determine a triangle formed by the circle centers (at least when all pairwise intersections have positive sizes). Thus what you are requesting is (in general, not in this particular case) likely (a) to be inconsistent with your actual data yet (b) to be impossible to do anyway.

Comment: This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713994/venn-diagram-in-r-proportional-and-color-shading-possible-semi-transparency-sup) may be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the hint of Penguin_Knight, you can try to draw it in `R`.

You did not specify what the intersection among A,B and C was, so I am assuming here to be zero.

```
library(VennDiagram)

venn.plot = draw.triple.venn(
              area1 = 1000,
              area2 = 3000,
              area3 = 5000,
              n12   = 200,
              n23   = 120,
              n13   = 0,
              n123  = 0,
                  category = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  fill = c("green", "red", "darkblue"),
                  euler.d=TRUE,
                  scaled=TRUE, ind = FALSE,
                  cat.pos=c(0,0,0))

grid.draw(venn.plot)
```

[image]

Unfortunately, it seems the `scaled` argument is not working in the VennDiagram package.

So, if by "precisely" you mean: areas proportional in size to the count values, here is another option, using the `Vennerable` package.
See more info [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/Vennerable/inst/doc/Venn.pdf?root=vennerable) on the package and [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=474) to download it.

```
library(Vennerable)

Venn_object = Venn(list(A = 1:1000,B = 801:3800, C = 3681:8680))
plot(Venn_object, doWeights = TRUE)
```

[image]

I could not find how to rotate the chart (horizontal position).